# Double vertical line for editors

Tags: vim, editor, jetbrains-ide, pep8

I once was given these materials to enable this helper for `vim` to show kind of a vertical line in order to help enforce PEP8 rules on line length limit at column 80:

```
"   Long lines highlighting.
nnoremap <Leader>H :call<SID>LongLineHLToggle()<cr>
hi OverLength ctermbg=none cterm=none
match OverLength /\%>80v/
fun! s:LongLineHLToggle()
    if !&diff
        if !exists('w:longlinehl')
            let w:longlinehl = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '.\%>80v', 0)
            echo "Long lines highlighted"
        else
            call matchdelete(w:longlinehl)
            unl w:longlinehl
            echo "Long lines unhighlighted"
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

Most GUI editors such as those embedded in JetBrains IDEs have a similar facility called something like *right margin line*.

I use all of this for marking the 80th column.

**Can I have an editor with the possibility of showing a further one lesser right margin line for comments at column 72?**

**Given enough time and effort I very much could have a similar facility in `vim` for marking text far beyond column 72 when *in comment*.** I guess it has been already coded by somebody somewhere at some point. **Do you already know where to find that snippet?**

Comment: I trans posted to [https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12787/13260](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12787/13260) because here nobody can or is willing to write any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally [muru](https://stackexchange.com/users/1042873/) gave solution at [vim.se](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12787/).

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please follow [IDEA-99875](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99875) for updates

Comment: Nice, thanks. Could you be so amazingly kind to ask your team about a `vim` workaround for it?